# PyQt5 I can't see background picture when I added layouts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qlayout

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui


def Window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    window.setWindowTitle("GORKIDEV Application")
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("telefon.png"))
    window.setGeometry(700,300,488,499)

    background_picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    background_picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("telefon.png"))

    okay = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Okay")
    cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel")

    h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

    h_box.addStretch()
    h_box.addWidget(okay)
    h_box.addWidget(cancel)

    v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    v_box.addStretch()
    v_box.addLayout(h_box)

    window.setLayout(v_box)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Window()
```

Hello guys, I just added background picture this window and after that I added 2 layout which include just two widget. 
When I execute codes I just see a bit part of picture on the up left side.

Where is the problem? Why I don't see picture clearly?

This is the output of the code.

[image]

Comment: With "background picture" do you mean an image that should also be *underneath* the buttons and other elements of the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `background_picture` into `layout`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui,  QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("GORKIDEV Application")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Ok.png"))
# ?      self.setGeometry(700, 300, 488, 499)
        self.resize(488, 499)

        background_picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        background_picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena2.png"))

        okay = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Okay")
        cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel")

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addWidget(okay)
        h_box.addWidget(cancel)

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_box.addWidget(background_picture, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # !!! +++
        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]